# A chance to lift the question ban

Tags: support

'If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.'

I would like to know when exactly I will have the possibility to ask a ban-lifting question?

For what period of time I will have this possibility and from what time point to what time point?

Comment: Just so you know @ccsann, this question bans are 100% automatic and nobody here has any way of changing them. They cannot be imposed or lifted by moderators. This is out of our hands, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though your [most recent question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/537342/117549) on the main site was asked at Aug 25 '19 , so 6 months after that would be approx Feb 25 '20. You can see your questions on your profile (select that tab), then sort them by newest -- that's what I did to find it.